# ClosedChannelException

Tags: java

Anyone tell me why i am getting this exception at `sc.connect`

( sc = SocketChannel)

```
/**
 * Verify socket is connected.  If not currently connected will attempt to connect
 * @return true if already connected or connection successfully established
 */
private synchronized boolean verifyConnection() {
    if (sc.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    try {
        if (!sc.isOpen()) {
            logger.info("Channel WebBroker->CC is CLOSED unexpectedly. Opening new channel " + getIpAddress() + ":" + getIpPort() + "");
            openChannel();
        }
        sc.socket().close();
        sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(getIpAddress(), getIpPort()));
        while(!sc.finishConnect()){
            Thread.sleep(1);    
        }
        logger.info("Connection established " + getIpAddress() + ":" + getIpPort());
        sc.socket().setKeepAlive(true);
        return sc.isConnected();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.info("failed to connect to " + getIpAddress() + ":" + getIpPort(), e);
        return false;
    }
}


private void openChannel() throws Exception {
    sc = SocketChannel.open();
    sc.socket().setKeepAlive(true);
    sc.socket().setSoTimeout(30000);
}
```

[ERROR]failed to connect to 10.201.1.53:8084

```
 java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.ensureOpenAndUnconnected(SocketChannelImpl.java:472) ~[na:1.6.0_07]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(SocketChannelImpl.java:486) ~[na:1.6.0_07]
```

Edit : Finally i found that this is because of the below line.

```
 sc.socket().close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't reconnect a socket. You have to create a new one.

You should also note that isConnected() only tells you whether you have ever connected the socket. It doesn't tell you the current state of the entire connection. Similarly isOpen() only tells you whether you have or haven't closed it yet: not whether the peer has done so. You can't in general write the method you are trying to write. The only reliable way to tell whether a TCP connection is still alive is to write to it. And in general the only reliable way to detected whether any resource is available is to try to use it. Don't try to predict the future. You still have to deal with write failures anyway: why write all that code twice?

Comment: Hi, Where i am reconnecting? And please tell me how to create a new socket instead of reconnecting?